# Trouble writing a string value with spaces to a form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to write a PHP file that pulls the names of products from a database and creates a button that automatically searches out that item by name on Ebay. I've been mostly successful, but I've found that, if my product name has spaces, the value written into the form will be concatenated at the space- i.e, passing the string "Red Barchetta" will appear as "Red" in the search bar

The specific problem occurs on the line down near the end:

input type="text" name="_nkw" value='.$row['name'].'

...where $row['name'] might be "Cosmic Catch", but "_nkw" winds up being "Cosmic"

I'm sure this is a rookie mistake, but there's clearly something I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'xxxxxxxxx'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'xxxxx'; // Username
$db_pass = 'xxxxxx'; // Password
$db_name = 'xxxx'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
}

$sql = 'SELECT * 
    FROM products';

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$query) {
    die ('SQL Error: '. mysqli_error($conn));
}


?>
<html>
<head>
<title>BMT Products</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #343d44;
        font-family: "segoe-ui", "open-sans", tahoma, arial;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    table {
        margin: auto;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe Ui";
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    h1 {
        margin: 25px auto 0;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    table td {
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    /* Table */
    .data-table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 14px;
        min-width: 537px;
    }

    .data-table th, 
    .data-table td {
        border: 1px solid #e1edff;
        padding: 7px 17px;
    }
    .data-table caption {
        margin: 7px;
    }

    /* Table Header */
    .data-table thead th {
        background-color: #508abb;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        border-color: #6ea1cc !important;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    /* Table Body */
    .data-table tbody td {
        color: #353535;
    }
    .data-table tbody td:first-child,
    .data-table tbody td:nth-child(4),
    .data-table tbody td:last-child {
        text-align: right;
    }

    .data-table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
        background-color: #f4fbff;
    }
    .data-table tbody tr:hover td {
        background-color: #ffffa2;
        border-color: #ffff0f;
    }

    /* Table Footer */
    .data-table tfoot th {
        background-color: #e5f5ff;
        text-align: right;
    }
    .data-table tfoot th:first-child {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .data-table tbody td:empty
    {
        background-color: #ffcccc;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Table 1</h1>
<table class="data-table">
    <caption class="title">BMT Products Database</caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>manufacturer</th>
            <th>brand</th>
            <th>year</th>
            <th>video</th>
            <th>image</th>
            <th>popularity</th>
            <th>ebay</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $path = 'getImage.php?id='.$row['id'];
        echo '<tr>

                <td>'.$row['id'].'</td>             
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['manufacturer'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['Brand'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['year'].'</td>   
                <td>'.$row['video'].'</td>
                <td><img src='.$path.' alt="" border=3 height=100 width=100></img></td> 
                <td>'.$row['popularity'].'</td>
                <td>
                    <form method="get" action="http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" target="_blank" >
                    <table style="margin:auto; font-family:arial; text-align:left; background:#ddd; border:1px solid #888; border-radius:.25em">
                    <tbody><tr><td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_ssn" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_sop" value="12">
                    <input type="text" name="_nkw" value='.$row['name'].'/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search">
                    </td></tr><tr><td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="LH_TitleDesc" value="1">
                    <small>include description</small>
                    </td></tr></tbody></table></form>
                </td>

            </tr>';


    }?>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really should quote the `value` value in your input field in your markup, as you're doing with `type` and `name`

Comment: @MarkBaker that's not just a side-note, that actually should fix this problem, right? The second word would be interpreted as another attribute, I believe.

Comment: P.S. You really don't need to post all the css in your code, forcing us to scroll to see the form, just post the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Do try and keep your code minimal. Including tons of CSS is just plain ridiculous.

Comment: MarkBaker and Don't Panic, that solved it- thank you very much! Changing the line to <input type="text" name="_nkw" value="'.$row['name'].'"/> fixed it- a rookie mistake on my part. Thanks everyone for your input (and I'll keep the code to a minimum next time,